# Compare Dictionaries for close enough match

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, dictionary

I am looking for a good way to compare two dictionaries which contain the information of a matrix. So the structure of my dictionaries are the following, both dictionaries have identical keys:

```
dict_1 = {("a","a"):0.01, ("a","b"): 0.02, ("a","c"): 0.00015, ...
dict_2 = {("a","a"):0.01, ("a","b"): 0.018, ("a","c"): 0.00014, ...
```

If I have to matrices, i.e. lists of list, I can use `numpy.allclose`. Is there something similar for dictionaries or is there a nice way to transform my dictionaries into such matrices?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham A truth value, like the `numpy.allclose` gives it would be nice.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that would make the assumption that dict_1.values() and dict_2.values() will return the list in the same key order. I can't see anything in the specification that says it will (although it seems to do so in practice).

Comment: @HannesOvrén Yes, this is the point. I can not guarantee the same order of keys.

Comment: Then see my suggested answer below.

Comment: @HannesOvrén I am currently trying it.

Comment: One could also argue that storing a matrix as a dict is not really great to begin with. Why are you not storing the matrix itself as a `numpy.array` and then just keep the index information ('a', 'b', ...) separately? Is it a sparse matrix? In that case I believe scipy has a sparse matrix implementation.

Comment: @HannesOvrén I used the dictionaries to not get lost in indices and to get rid of the look-up step if I store the index information seperately.

Comment: As long as you are aware of, and OK with,  the overhead in space and computation time, that's fine.

Comment: @HannesOvrén So, my way will take more time? I was not aware of that. In this case I will think of going back to lists/arrays.

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you are doing, so I can't answer that question. It *will* however take up more space than storing a `numpy.array` and a list of X/Y indices. If you don't have a problem with space or computation time I'd let it be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63713/discussion-between-swot-and-hannes-ovren).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way I could think of:

```
keylist = dict_1.keys()
array_1 = numpy.array([dict_1[key] for key in keylist])
array_2 = numpy.array([dict_2[key] for key in keylist])

if numpy.allclose(array_1, array_2):
    print('Equal')
else:
    print('Not equal')
```

Comment: Clever way of ensuring the order is the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is a numpy-function, used in unit testing to compare 2 numbers. You can set the desired precision via `significant`.

```
import numpy as np

dict_1 = {("a","a"):0.01, ("a","b"): 0.02, ("a","c"): 0.00015}
dict_2 = {("a","a"):0.01, ("a","b"): 0.018, ("a","c"): 0.00014}

def compare_dicts(dict_1, dict_2, significant=2):
    for k in dict_1:
        try:
            np.testing.assert_approx_equal(dict_1[k], dict_2[k], 
                significant=significant)
        except AssertionError:
            return False
        return True

compare_dicts(dict_1, dict_2)
```

This will take the keys from one dict and compare each item in both dicts.

See the details for the numpy-function used [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_approx_equal.html).

Comment: It will throw an `AssertionError` when the values are not equal. Depending on your use case, you can catch that error.

Comment: actually I do not need to compare only the values of identical key, so this is a bit too general.

Comment: You mentioned *both dictionaries have identical keys*. So what are you looking to compare? The values in order?

Comment: I need to compare if the values of say both `("a","a")` are close enough. I do not want to compare say `("a","a")` and  `("a","c")`. I mentioned the identical keys to point out that both dictionaries have the same size and that they contain "comparable" information.

Comment: That's what both answers are doing currently. You are using those tuples as keys. So we compare `dict1[("a","a")]` and `dict2[("a","a")]`.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misread your explanation. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to get the values in default order and `numpy.allclose` :

```
>>> import numpy
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dict_1 = {("a","a"):0.01, ("a","b"): 0.02, ("a","c"): 0.00015}
>>> dict_2 = {("a","a"):0.01, ("a","b"): 0.018, ("a","c"): 0.00014}
>>> d2=OrderedDict(sorted(dict_2.items(), key=lambda t: t)) #d2.values() -> [0.01, 0.018, 0.00014]
>>> d1=OrderedDict(sorted(dict_1.items(), key=lambda t: t))
>>> atol=0.0001 # as example
>>> numpy.allclose(d1.values(),d2.values())
False
```

Comment: `OrderedDict` seems like overkill. `values2 = [dict_2[k] for k in sorted(dict_2.keys())]`. Since they have the same keys, this will return them in the same order for both dictionaries.

Comment: Last step should be `allclose(d1.values(), d2.values())` to match the question. But I second the above comment that using OrderedDict for this is overkill (although for different reasons).

Comment: yep , i edit the answer , thanks for reminding but what you mean by overkill ?

Comment: Unless you need to do the value extraction often, then using an OrderedDict (and thus requiring the sorting step above) is overkill compared to simply extracting the value lists using any key order as long as that order is the same for both dicts (i.e. what I suggested in my answer).